# How can i assign an action to rightbarbuttonitem with an edit style?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have an edit rightbarbuttonitem in my view in navigation bar. I set it up with the help of storyboard/IB, not programmatically. Now, all i want is to assign an action when the "done" barbuttonitem is pressed (not edit).

Is there a way to achieve it? I tried manually through `-(IBAction)`, but it's not working. Also, i want to perform the action on selected items in UITableView. So if you give me an idea, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

That button calls the method

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can implement it and it will get called everytime your edit/done button gets tapped. All you have to do is check the button's title property to see when it's showing done and when it's showing edit

Comment: I agree with this, might as well use standard code if it's there

Answer (score 0):

If you declared your button as an IBOutlet then all you'd need to do is use the synthesised variable on your .m as so:

```
_yourBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(runMethod)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _yourBarButton;
```

Then you'd have to declare your run method:

```
-(void)runMethod
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: What if i didn't declare? Is it necessary to declare it? I tried the similar code without IB0outlet and it didn't workout.

Comment: Not necessarily. But then you'd have to write UIBarButtonItem *yourBarButton as your declaration in your .m

Comment: I did the same. But it creates another button. I want to overwrite the same on "EDIT" barbuttonitem when it changes to "done".

Comment: Yeah, I'm just showing you how I'd do it. I seldomly use Interface Builder anymore. Just delete the button from your Interface Builder and the one you create from this code will be the one you'd use. :)

Comment: without that, i wouldn't be able to select tableview cells, right? which is a problem here.

Comment: You should be able to access the tableview cells either way. Not sure how though, you'd have to google that bit...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16158/discussion-between-monis-manzoor-and-suiz-uzcategui)